# How to get Principal Id of a User in Workflow

Tags: designer-workflow, rest

I am trying to set unique permissions on a list for specific users, and in order to do this I must be able to pull the principalId of the user from within a workflow to be used in a REST call in the workflow. How can I go about acquiring this information?

Currently I am getting the user's Id from a Person field in the list and using that as the principalId, but my REST calls are not working correctly and am wondering if this could be because I am not inputting the correct principalId. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
https://mysites.com/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('TestList')/items([%Variable: Current Item:ID%])/roleassignments/addroleassignment(principalid=[%Variable: personId%], roleDefId=1073741828)
```

Comment: Can you show your REST call?

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to include that.

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke following REST call from the Workflow

```
 http://your_sp_site.sharepoint.com/_api/web/siteusers
```

and get the user in question (using filter) and get the `PrincipalId` into a variable. And use it as part of the actual REST call.

```
http://siteurl/_api/web/siteusers?$select=Id,Title&$filter=substringof('\username', Title)
```

Comment: I may have a lack of understanding, is the Id from this call and the principalId that i'm looking for the same Id or are there separate fields?

Comment: Its the same. For testing purpose you can open this in browser and double check before implementation.

Comment: Is the '\username' the same thing as the LoginName? I am entering the username and it won't pull back any values.