# Rest web service principalid

Tags: rest

Any URI that can be used to find the `principalid` for user name and group name via Rest.

I can only use separate URIs to find it.

Comment: Which URLs you are currently using? Did you try this URL `/_api/web/siteusers`.

Comment: Maybe here also some related information: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/125378/how-to-get-principal-id-of-a-user-in-workflow

Answer (score 0):

Get group ID:

> /web/sitegroups/getbyname

Get user ID:

> /web/siteusers@v

I have a field that contain user name / group name , how to distinguish it or 
a URI that can obtain the principal ID.